# Wordpress: list category tree only from one category

Tags: wordpress, list, categories

I got a lot of categories on my page, and made them hierarchical, something like this:

```
News
Fun
...
Somestuff
- child of somestuff
- - grandchild of somestuff
- - 2nd grandchild of somestuff
- 2nd child of somestuff
```

Now i want to create some navigation only for "somestuff" category, that only displays the child and grandchild elements, exactly like this:

> `<ul>
>
>     <li>child of somestuff
>
>       <ul>
>
>         <li>grandchild of somestuff</li>
>
>         <li>2nd grandchild of somestuff</li>
>
>       </ul>
>
>     </li>
>
>     <li> ... and so on </li>
>
>   </ul>`

What i tryd first, is this: (135 => somestuff)

> $args = array(
>           'show_option_all'   => false,
>           'orderby'           => 'name',
>           'order'             => 'ASC',
>           'style'             => 'list',
>           'hierarchical'      => true,
>           'title_li'          => false,
>           'depth'             => 5,
>           'hide_empty'        => false,
>           'child_of'          => '135'
>           );
>
> wp_list_categories( $args );

However this won't display the "grand child" elements. I need some help with this.
~

Comment: Could you check again? This exact code _does_ display grand child categories for me.

Answer (score 0):

And yes this works, thanks Dogbert, however the reason why this didn't work for me the first time is this:

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/child-category-missing-from-admin-list-but-its-there

After going to phpmyadmin, and playing with fix table a bit, it works again in the admin menu, and on the page...
Annoying bug here, and no real solution?! :(

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
    wp_list_categories( array(
   'child_of'            => 135, //your category id
        'current_category'    => 0,
        'depth'               => 0,
        'echo'                => 1,
        'hide_empty'          => 1,
        'hide_title_if_empty' => false,
        'hierarchical'        => true,
        'order'               => 'DESC',
        'orderby'             => 'count',
        'show_count'          => 0,
        'show_option_none'    => __( 'No categories' ),
        'style'               => 'list',
        'taxonomy'            => 'category',
        'title_li'            => 0,
        'use_desc_for_title'  => 0,
    ) ); 
?>
```